# Issue with Parse & Facebook

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I started to develop an app using Parse and Facebook.
I've added both SDKs.

This is my ViewController code(The fbLogIn is a button of "Connect with Facebook"):

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func fbLogIn(sender: AnyObject) {
    var permissions = ["email"]
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
            } else {
                println("User logged in through Facebook!")
            }
        } else {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    }
}}
```

This is the App Delegate code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    Parse.setApplicationId("*Cencored ID*",
        clientKey: "*Cencored clientkey*")
    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL,
    sourceApplication: String?,
    annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
}
```

}

This is the bugs:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXBqQ.png

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar experience.  Look the frameworks in your project, check to see if you have ParseFacebookUtils.framework and ParseCrashReporting.framework.  If you do, remove them from your project.  You need the ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework though, so leave that in there.

Comment: Amazing! It works! I deleted it as you said, did Clean, Build % Run!